# Create a route action which use address from filter expression

Tags: mailgun

I want to create a route action which use address from filter expression.
my filter expression is

```
match_recipient("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?P<domain>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)")
```

and I write the following action

```
forward("http://\g<domain>/mail/mailgun/")
```

but it shows

> Destination must be publicly accessible

please help me

Comment: For me this was happening when I had an identical route defined (same exact `match_recipient` and `forward` fields).